# XAML Newbie Question

Tags: xaml

Can anyone recommend some reference sites and books for learning XAML?

I basically need to get up to speed as quickly as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's hard for books to keep pace with such a fast-changing technology -- so for example [XAML in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526733), which was quite good when published, has already been made obsolete by new WPF releases.  So you should probably be best advised to stick with up-to-date online resources, such as [MSDN's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) overview.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [XAML Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Josh Smith's [blog](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/) and his new ebook, [Advanced MVVM](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/). I hate DRM but this book was worth the hassle.